# Renderscript and garbage collector

Tags: garbage-collection, renderscript

Recently I modified my code to store everything in the renderscript (before that I copied the data back and forth wasn't effective), but now the garbage collector is collecting garbage like crazy. (Still the app is preforming better this way.)

I can't figure out what needs to be collected, I use everything I don't create new arrays in the functions, which I call frequently. My only idea is that if I do this:

```
void __attribute__((kernel)) diffuseVelocityY(float in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
     velocityY_prev[x] = velocityY[x] + a*(velocityY_prev[x-1] + velocityY_prev[x+1] + velocityY_prev[x-(width)] + velocityY_prev[x+(width)])/(1+(4*a));
}
```

it creates a temperaly pointer for it because I'm using data from the same pointer that I want to update(I have no idea if this is the way it works). I tried to change it, so it puts the data in an empty pointer and after it finishes I copy the data to the right place. It seemd that it collected less garbage but there was still garbage collection and the preformance went down aswell.

I uploaded my code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5xcsgsfjeb5ph53/AACRI9y9wdO-TkWdPUNDer8Fa?dl=0) if someone wants to look(the _befores are from before I modified the code).

I have no idea how to stop the garbage collection, I hope someone can help.

One of the methods:

```
void set_bnd_densiy_prev(int b){
        for (int i = 1; i <= gridSizeY; i++) {
            density_prev[IX(0, i)] = (b == 1 ? -density_prev[IX(1, i)] : density_prev[IX(1, i)]);
            density_prev[IX(gridSizeX + 1, i)] = (b == 1 ? -density_prev[IX(gridSizeX, i)] : density_prev[IX(gridSizeX, i)]);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= gridSizeX; i++) {
            density_prev[IX(i, 0)] = (b == 2 ? -density_prev[IX(i, 1)] : density_prev[IX(i, 1)]);
            density_prev[IX(i, gridSizeY + 1)] = (b == 2 ? -density_prev[IX(i, gridSizeY)] : density_prev[IX(i, gridSizeY)]);
        }
    density_prev[IX(0 ,0 )] = 0.5f*(density_prev[IX(1,0 )]+density_prev[IX(0 ,1)]);
    density_prev[IX(0 ,gridSizeY+1)] = 0.5f*(density_prev[IX(1,gridSizeY+1)]+density_prev[IX(0 ,gridSizeY )]);
    density_prev[IX(gridSizeX+1,0 )] = 0.5f*(density_prev[IX(gridSizeX,0 )]+density_prev[IX(gridSizeX+1,1)]);
    density_prev[IX(gridSizeX+1,gridSizeY+1)] = 0.5f*(density_prev[IX(gridSizeX,gridSizeY+1)]+density_prev[IX(gridSizeX+1,gridSizeY )]);
}
```

Code generated from it:

```
   private final static int mExportFuncIdx_set_bnd_densiy_prev = 3;
    public void invoke_set_bnd_densiy_prev(int b) {
    FieldPacker set_bnd_densiy_prev_fp = new FieldPacker(4);
    set_bnd_densiy_prev_fp.addI32(b);
    invoke(mExportFuncIdx_set_bnd_densiy_prev, set_bnd_densiy_prev_fp);
}
```

Comment: Are your `velocityY` and `velocityY_prev` bound to memory within your RenderScript?  What are you doing before and after calling `foreach_diffuseVelocityY()`?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I allocated memory to them. After calling it I involke `set_bnd_velocityY_prev()` it modifies data in the same array/pointer that was modified in the `foreach_diffuseVelocityY()`. Before that I do the same thing with an another array/pointer. They get called in every OpenGL draw.

Comment: The RS calls are mostly thin wrappers around JNI code to call into the core RS engine, so there should be minimal java objects being created.  That being said, your smoke test code is a good size so it may be tough to narrow down exactly what could be causing the problem.  Have you tried using the systrace functionality to get a better look at things?

Comment: it seems that the functions that I call with invoke causes the problem if I comment them out the garbage collector stays quiet. So basically every functions in smoke.rs that contains the term "set_bnd" somehow causes the problem but still don't know why

Comment: Can you post your auto generated ScriptC class? At least the source for one of the problem methods.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I posted one of the methods you can download the full sources from the link above

Comment: Could the cause be linked to the generated code? There is a lot of "new FieldPacker" involved, re-using the fieldpacker when possible instead of creating a new object each time would help.

Comment: @AladinQ Sure it would but it is auto generated and I don't know what is the need for them. In my code I'm using only pre allocated arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the function args because renderscript needs to create Fieldpackers to handle them. So if you have the same problem remove the function args then copy paste the function and modify the variables and call the different functions not pretty but it works.

(Thanks thebaron for your help)